# How to plot separately for each column without looping through columns in a pandas df?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot each column separately in df with x axis as the index and y axis as the respective columns. I can loop through the columns  and plot them but it is too slow. Any ideas to do this without looping. ??

I have created a dummy dataframe below. It is way too slow for bigger columns.  Many Thanks for help.

```
DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=('A','B','C','D'))


for j in range(len(data.columns)):

    y = data.iloc[:, j].values
    x = data.index 
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Just to make sure: You have n columns and want to create n figures? The time this takes is determined by creating the figures, indendent of using a loop or not. So maybe you want to explain more the actual problem you have?

Comment: Yes.. I want to create n figures. Is there any way to make it run faster..

Comment: I would recommend you state your problem clearly in the question. "run faster" is not really clear. Because your code would also block at each `show`, speed seems to be rather irrelevant.